# Date time handling in flex

Tags: date, flex4

I have a service that give me a date time string in the following format

2012-03-19T12:59:00Z

I need to convert that into a Date object in flex 4. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Date.parse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse%28%29).

It looks like you might need to do a String.replace() or similar operation on the String you pass to the parse() method, for it to succeed.

A better solution, if it is under your control, is to have the service return the date/time string as an [epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (in milliseconds). Then on the Flash side, you can just [construct a new](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#Date%28%29) `Date` object passing in the time (in milliseconds) to the constructor:

```
var dateTime:Date = new Date(epoch_time_in_millis);
```

Comment: alas its not in my control but i sorted it out some otherway, but thanks, that would've worked too